# Stored procedure - Store query into parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm trying to store a query into a variable and here is what I'm doing :

```
@check int = [return_code] FROM [dbo].[RESULT] WHERE [code_test] = 'T3005_das'
```

The return code field only contains the 0 or 1 value. When I'm trying to do this, here's the error message I've got :

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure V116_T3005, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

I don't really understand why it's not working properly as I've followed samples of code on the internet.

Any idea?

**EDIT** : Here's my edited procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE V116_T3005
    DECLARE @check int 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @check = [code_retour] FROM [dbo].[RESULTAT] WHERE [code_test] = 'T3005_das'
    --logical code
END
```

Now I'm getting these errors :

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure V116_T3005, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure V116_T3005, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: seems you missed the word `SELECT`

Comment: Remove `Declare` from your Stored Proc. Is `@check` your output variable?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @check int

select @check = [return_code] 
FROM [dbo].[RESULT] 
WHERE [code_test] = 'T3005_das'
```

Comment: Thank for your help. However, I still got errors. Could you check my edit?

Answer (score 0):

If @check is an output parameter the word `declare` should be omitted. If it is not it should be declared **after** `BEGIN` and if so, I would suggest:
`declare @check integer = (select [code_retour] FROM [dbo].[RESULTAT] WHERE [code_test] = 'T3005_das');`

BTW are you sure that `select [code_retour] FROM [dbo].[RESULTAT] WHERE [code_test] = 'T3005_das'` will **always** return one value? Otherwise error will be raised.